# How to create a video streaming app that allows two video streams from a device with multiple users viewing the two streams

Tags: streaming

I just need to information of how I can create a streaming server that allows more than one viewer to watch 2 video streams coming from two separate devices?

So the app will have two video panels which are streaming from two individual devices like an android phone and allowing more than one viewer to watch the two live streams.